I cannot color the active page number when paginating
I show the data I pulled from the Mysql database as pages. As  , I create page numbers according to the number of records and the record to be shown on each page. But I cannot change the color of the active page. And I can't add forward and back links.
I show the data I pulled from the Mysql database as pages. As  , I create page numbers according to the number of records and the record to be shown on each page. When I click on the page numbers, the next record comes up. No problem so far
//define total number of results you want per page  
$results_per_page = 2;  

//find the total number of results stored in the database  
$query = "select * from urunler";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);  

//determine the total number of pages available  
$number_of_page = ceil ($number_of_result / $results_per_page);  

//determine which page number visitor is currently on  
if (!isset ($_GET['page']) ) {  
    $page = 1;
} else {  
    $page = $_GET['page'];  
}  

//determine the sql LIMIT starting number for the results on the displaying page  
$page_first_result = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;  

//retrieve the selected results from database   
$query = "SELECT * FROM urunler LIMIT " . $page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    ?>

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['fiyat'];
   }
for($page = 1; $page<= $number_of_page; $page++) {  
echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0 mr-3 shadow-sm border-top-0 border-left-0 text-dark" href = "shop.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';

} 

